# .htaccess file not working on Filezilla for a simple React app

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router, filezilla

So I'm having some trouble configuring my .htaccess file on Filezilla. I read online that in order for the routing on my app to work I have to create the file and put some code into it. I have mostly seen these 2 codes:

1.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

another code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

With both codes I still get a 404 error after I refresh a page (not the index page). I also can't see the content of the index page. Only when I go to it via a link then I see the content. I also added the **homepage** in package.json file and put **exact** on my route to the index page so it doesn't show on the other pages. Please help, cause this has been bothering me for a while and it's probably a simple fix that I can't find. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, your 1st code should work, where is your htaccess is placed? And where is your index.html placed?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i have my .htaccess file in my subfolder /app01 where i have put the contents of my build folder into as well. I have 3 folders. The root one that is still blank, a /todo folder where I have created a simple one page todo app and then a /app01 folder for this dummy app that I'm working on. The index.html is also placed in that subfolder /app01. It came from the build folder of my app.

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at a cached response? Always use a fresh anonymous browser window to test.

Comment: Please add the exact URLs that are requested to the question. And the layout of your server side file system.